# Breaking out off a WHILE loop which is inside a FOR LOOP

Tags: java

In Java, what is the direct method of getting out of a WHILE loop which is inside a WHILE loop and which is inside a FOR loop?
The structure should look something like this:

```
For{
.
.
   While{
   .
   .
   .
     While{
     .
     .
     <Stuck here. Want to break Free of all Loops>;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a label and a break

```
here:

    while (...) {
       for (...) {

         if (...) break here;
       }
   }
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 3):

> Want to break Free of all Loops

You can use a plain `break;` to end the immediate containing loop and in Java you can use `labeled` break to end an arbitrary loop. Like

```
out: for(;;) {
    while(true) {
        while (true) {
            // ....
            break out;
        }
    }
 }
```

The label is the text before `:` (and the word after `break` in the example above).

**Note**:An unlabeled break statement terminates the innermost switch, for, while, or do-while statement, but **a labeled break terminates an outer statement**.

[Source of the Note](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: I like your answer but I added some info to your answer hope you do not mind.